# Lambda Expression String Comparison

Tags: c#, string, lambda, comparison

I have been trying to determine why my lambda expression is not working.  It should be checking CHECK_STATUS_CD to see if there is a "1" or a "0". However, no matter the value it goes into the if statement.  Below is the if statement with the expression.

```
 using (DocumentEntities dbConnection = new DocumentEntities())
 {
     if (dbConnection.CHECKs.Any(c => c.FUSION_CHECK_ID == fusionCheckID))
     {
          if (dbConnection.CHECKs.Any(s => s.CHECK_STATUS_CD == "0"))
          {
              PotentialChecks.Check.Add(check);
           }
      }
      else
      {
         PotentialChecks.Check.Add(check);
      }
}
```

I have attempted to compare the CHECK_STATUS_CD and the "0" in multiple ways including s.CHECK_STATUS_CD.Equals("0"); however, I receive the same result when any value is passed through.  How should I write my lambda expression so that if CHECK_STATUS_CD is equal to "1" it will pass over the if statement?

Thanks

Comment: hard to say. what is `CHECKs` actually?

Comment: What if `CHECKs` has records with CHECK_STATUS_CD == "0" as well as records with CHECK_STATUS_CD == "1"? If you state your situation and desired outcome precisely, you probably will realize the solution  quickly by yourself...

Comment: CHECKs is a database table.  It houses check information, including the status.  I will include a larger portion of code for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, we had to modify the second if statement. Below is the same piece of code updated with what we had to do.

```
 using (DocumentEntities dbConnection = new DocumentEntities())
 {
     if (dbConnection.CHECKs.Any(c => c.FUSION_CHECK_ID == fusionCheckID))
     {
         var currentCheck = dbConnection.CHECKs.Where(x => x.FUSION_CHECK_ID 
                            == check.CheckID && x.CHECK_STATUS_CD == 
                            "0").FirstOrDefault();

         if (currentCheck != null)
         {
             PotentialChecks.Check.Add(check);
         }
      }
      else
      {
          PotentialChecks.Check.Add(check);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CHECK_STATUS_CD` is of type string there there shouldn't be an issue, but would need to see the `CHECKs` class to get a clearer understanding.

If `CHECK_STATUS_CD` is not of type `string` then you might want to consider using `.Equals()`